# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{3x+2y}-\frac{3}{2}$ without stuff from higher-order differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> I'm trying to solve this equation: 
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{3x+2y}-\frac{3}{2}$$ 
>   without using stuff from higher-order differential equations.

I've tried using substitution $ w=\frac{y}{x} $, but it doesn't really help. After using that substitution, I get 
$$ \frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{3+2w}-\frac{3}{2}w}{x} $$ 
which isn't a differential equation with separable variables.

Can somebody please help me out with this one?

Comment: Which *stuff* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $u = 3x + 2y$. It should then be separable.

Comment: I literally tried doing that and I ended up thinking it can't be done that way. So dumb >.<. Thank you :-)

Comment: (+) good luck....

Comment: @E.H.E thanks..

Comment: (+1) I feel so stupid now looking at my solution...

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging and squaring gives
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+3\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac94=3x+2y$$
Differentiating gives that
$$2\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+3\cdot\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=3+2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\left(2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}+3\right)=2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}+3$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=1$$
$$y=\frac12x^2+C_1x+C_2$$
Plugging this in the original equation we have
$$x+C_1=\sqrt{x^2+(2C_1+3)x+2C_2}-\frac32$$
$$\left(x+C_1+\frac32\right)^2=x^2+(2C_1+3)x+2C_2$$
$$x^2+\left(2C_1+3\right)x+\left(C_1+\frac32\right)^2=x^2+(3+2C_1)x+2C_2$$
$$\therefore C_2=\frac12\left(C_1+\frac32\right)^2$$
Hence the general solution is
$$y=\frac12x^2+C_1x+\frac12\left(C_1+\frac32\right)^2$$

Comment: You can get the results cheaper. For $y''=1$, insert $y'=x+c$ into the squared equation, for the second case insert $y=-\frac32$ into the first order equation.